# ApiRTC "peertopeer_call" not working on host

Tags: web, webrtc

I've downloaded "[ApiRTC-examples](https://github.com/apizee/ApiRTC-examples)" and opened it up by Xampp on a Windows 10 machine. In this case, everything goes well and I can connect to the "peertopeer_call" page on the machine by other clients over the local network.
[image]

I have a 2GB host on the internet and uploaded "ApiRTC-examples" there. The problem is, CSS not loaded and it doesn't give me any number for registration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My domain didn't have an SSL certification for creating HTTPS connections. I've added an SSL certificate for the host and domain, consequently, the problem solved.